# How to setup Istio on IBM Kubernetes cluster? How to create the gateway?

Tags: websphere, hyperledger, istio

I was trying to configure Istio inside IBM Kubernetes cluster where Hyperledger fabric is running. Injected Side car chairs and showing the list for running pods also. But dont know how to proceed to view the traffic from other pods and to create custom gateway for it.

Tried to create the custom gateway, but it didt succeed to get traffic